# Ajax error when using minified version of prototype.js

Tags: magento-1.9, ajax, prototype-js, cdn

When using minified version of the PrototypeJS. (official version from Google CDN)
ajax stops working. Console shows error:

```
"TypeError: e is not a function"
```

Is there a way to fix this? We really would prefer to use minified version for a production site.

Related to:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34887126/magento-cant-run-dataflow-profiles-ajax-error-uncaught-typeerror-e-is-not-a

Answer (score 0):

it's a very common issue not just on Magento. It's happening because of some verifications that needed to be checked before minifying.

You may want to try running [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) on your Javascript code before you try to minimize it. JSLint might highlight some issues, which could allow you to minimize your code without error.

> I recommend you try another 'minification' tool like the YUI Compressor to then upload for your CDN or just to use on your install.

Here are two articles I've found on 'A List Apart,' that may interest you, looking at the YUI Compressor.

["Better JavaScript Minification"](https://alistapart.com/article/better-javascript-minification)

["JavaScript Minification Part II"](https://alistapart.com/article/javascript-minification-part-II)